# curl with oAuth login flow

Tags: bash, curl, oauth, fiware

I'm trying to implement a oAuth login flow in a bash script.

The request I need to send to my API is:

```
curl -X GET 'http://account.lab.fiware.org/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my_client_id&redirect_uri=my_redirect_uri&state=testing'
```

I keep getting a `301 Moved Permanently` Apache message referencing to the same address..

When trying the same url from my browser - it does work.

Is there a way that I can copy the browser behaviour with curl?

So, once the above request has been made I will be able to see the redirect location in order to get the token from?

Answer (score 0):

that OAuth2 grant is thought to be used from a web browser. You have other grant types that can be user from server side. Take a look to:

http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#oauth2-authentication

BR

Comment: But doesnt it still redirect the user to a login and approval page?